# How do I use sed to create a bulleted list?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following list:

```
➜ cat list.txt
job titles
    site reliability engineer
    automation
        automation engineer
        automation architect
        integration specialists
```

I want to get the following `list2.txt`:

```
* job titles
    * site reliability engineer
    * automation
        * automation engineer
        * automation architect
        * integration specialists
```

I'm pretty sure this is a good job for `sed`. I know how to get the the "start of the line"

```
➜ sed 's/^/foo/g' list.txt
foojob titles
foo    site reliability engineer
foo    automation
foo        automation engineer
foo        automation architect
foo        integration specialists
```

And I thought I might be able to get "the start of the line followed by any number of characters until the start of a word", however this didn't work.

```
➜ sed 's/^.*\</foo/g' list.txt
job titles
    site reliability engineer
    automation
        automation engineer
        automation architect
        integration specialists
```

So now I'm wondering, how do I replace "the start of the line until the start of a word, with all of that except a * appended"? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to find the first non-whitespace character, and place the bullet before it

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]/* &/' list.txt
* job titles
    * site reliability engineer
    * automation
        * automation engineer
        * automation architect
        * integration specialists
```

Comment: thanks you! Does the `[^[:blank:]]` mean "any character not a blank line" and the `&` the match from before?

Comment: @mbigras `[^[:blank:]]` means any single character excluding horizontal whitespace (essentially space or horizontal tab) - see [POSIX Bracket Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). `[^ \t]` or `[^[:space:]]` should also work here. Yes `&` in the replacement refers to the matched pattern.